# Show data from multiple tables in MVC Webgrid

Tags: model-view-controller, webgrid

**I have 3 tables AAA,BBB,CCC. I have to show perticuler columns from those 3 tables in webgrid.** All 3 tables have their relation via primary key itemcode.
please suggest me how can i **get the data in MVC webgrid**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can join the tables and make a projection of the columns you need so you'll bind it as one "table" to the webgrid.

Comment: But I have add the edit facility also on the same...

Comment: There will be a need to write your saving logic that will update your entities from your viewmodel (columns projection in your case).

Comment: Hi. peter will you please provide me any sample code. for displaying data from multiple tables in webgrid. I didn't get solution till date

Comment: Hi Deepak. How are so far you displaying just data from one table in the webgrid?